# How to strip a GET property from the URL using PHP

Tags: php

I have the following function that get's the current page URL:

```
<?php

    // get current page url
    function currentPageUrl() {

        $pageURL = 'http';

        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}

        $pageURL .= "://";

        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }


        echo $pageURL;

    }

?>
```

Which prints:

http://localhost/gallery.php?id=23&type=main

I want to remove "&type=main" which is present in the url. So before echoing $pageURL I add the following line:

```
$pageUrl = preg_replace("&type=main", "", $pageURL);
```

But it still returns the full url including type=main. How can I get rid of that from the url?

Comment: Do you want to remove the `type` parameter *period*, or only when its value is "main"?

Comment: @ Peter Bailey, I want to remove both.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to :

- use [`parse_url`](http://fr.php.net/parse_url) or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to extract the list of parameters as a string
- use **[`parse_str`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)** to transform the query string to an array containing each parameter and its value -- indexed by parameters names.
- Do some magic on that array :

  - do what you have to to filter it
  - For example, `unset($array['type']);` could probably help ;-)
  - If needed, add more parameters to that array
- And, then, use **[`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query)** to re-build a query-string.

*A bit more complex than string manipulations, of course -- but much more reliable, I'd say ;-)*

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a url into [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). It will return an array from which you can rebuild as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pageUrl = str_replace('&type=main', '', $pageURL);
```

Comment: Weird, still same problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

did you try any other $_SERVER variables?
there are plenty and some of them already contain everything you need without any replace

```
phpinfo(32);
```

will show you all

Answer (score 0):

PHP identifiers are case sensitive. You probably meant to assign it to the same variable.

```
$pageURL = preg_replace("&type=main", "", $pageURL);
```

Either that, or you need to change the remnant of code to use `$pageUrl` instead of `$pageURL`.